# Does the grouped function from the List API return a list of lists on the same order?

Tags: scala, collections

I have a function that receives a list of objects. I want to partition that list in groups of fixed size, do something with the groups and return a list of objects in the same order that I received them.

I'm using the function `grouped`, from the `List` API. Something like this:

```
val listOfLists = inputList.grouped(FIXED_SIZE).toList
```

The scala-lang site is down, so what I see on the documentation of the method is:

```
  /** Partitions elements in fixed size ${coll}s.
   *  @see [[scala.collection.Iterator]], method `grouped`
   *
   *  @param size the number of elements per group
   *  @return An iterator producing ${coll}s of size `size`, except the
   *          last will be less than size `size` if the elements don't divide evenly.
   */
  def grouped(size: Int): Iterator[C] =
    iterator.grouped(size).map(fromSpecific)
```

I don't see anything related to the order there, so my question is, is this function **guaranteed** to always return the list of lists in order? E.g. for a batch size of 2:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) returns List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While the docs are not very clear about it, the underlying implementation uses an `Iterator` so yes, the elements will preserver the input order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, this is guaranteed. The documentation may not be 100% clear (though it is arguably intrinsic to the definition of an `Iterator` for an ordered collection), but this ordering is assumed by a large amount of code so this behaviour is never going to change.

Note that the `grouped` method is a degenerate case of the `sliding` method where the `step` and `size` are the same.

```
def grouped[T](list: List[T], size: Int) = list.sliding(size, size)
```

It makes even less sense for `sliding` to deliver results out of order, and in practice they are implemented using the same underlying mechanism.